# Select top 10 records in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

how can i query to CRM Dynamics for top 50 records like top in sqlserver.

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want paging: [Is it possible to limit the amount of results returned in a response when using a QueryExpression in CRM 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236020/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-amount-of-results-returned-in-a-response-when-using-a/3236730#3236730)

Comment: Question linked to refers to CRM 4, but it works identically for CRM 2011.

Comment: I think that TopCount is needed rather than paging.

Comment: Yes, at the time this was originally answered it wasn't available. TopCount can also be used to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

You need the QueryExpression property **TopCount** :

```js
var query = new QueryExpression(entity) {
     ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(someColumns),
     Criteria = {
         Conditions = ...
     },
     TopCount = 50
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch xml something like below:

```
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <attribute name="fullname" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```